# How can I add an image (logo) in context area, for example, H1 - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am completely new to anything web design or coding related. I realize that this question may be very simple and might seem extremely basic. I've searched and can't find any help, although I am not sure I am searching the right phrases.

I am playing around with a bootstrap template and would like to replace the H1 text with a logo image. Can anyone give me any tips on how to do this? Do I need to modify the CSS to achieve this, or can I put an image directly into the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. My problem was that my image was within a folder inside of the folder containing my Index.html rather than directly in the same folder as index.html.

Comment: <h1><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"></h1>